# Why does my scrollbar only scroll in one direction?

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar, paint

Im trying to scroll Edit Field child windows that are created in a dynamic loop like this:

```
 for(int x = 0; x<//Some Predefined Number of Windows decided by the user; x ++)
            {
                int m = //Some Predefined spacing determined by the Programmer
                EditBoxes = CreateWindow("Edit","Witness ",
                                         WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|WS_TABSTOP ,0,
                                         m,250,16,hwndx,NULL,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
            }
```

Heres How I'm trying to use ScrollWindowEx:

```
 case WM_VSCROLL:

{
    xNewPos = si.nPos;
     si.cbSize = sizeof(&si);
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    GetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&si);





    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
   case SB_TOP:
        si.nPos = si.nMin;
        break;

    // User clicked the END keyboard key.
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        si.nPos = si.nMax;
        break;

    // User clicked the top arrow.
    case SB_LINEUP:

        if(si.nPos>si.nMin)
        si.nPos = si.nPos-1;
        break;

    // User clicked the bottom arrow.
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        if(si.nPos<si.nMax)
        si.nPos -= 1;
        break;

    // User clicked the scroll bar shaft above the scroll box.
    case SB_PAGEUP:
        si.nPos -= si.nPage;
        break;

    // User clicked the scroll bar shaft below the scroll box.
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        si.nPos += si.nPage;
        break;

    // User dragged the scroll box.
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
        cout << si.nTrackPos;
        break;

    default:

       break;
    }
    si.fMask = SIF_POS;


     SetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&si,TRUE);
     SetScrollPos(hwnd,SB_VERT,si.nPos,TRUE);

    if(si.nPos != xNewPos)
    {

    ScrollWindowEx(hwnd,0,si.nPos,(RECT*)NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN| SW_INVALIDATE| SW_ERASE );

    }
```

I'm Able to get the scrollbar to scroll down or up depending on if Ii make the si.nPos negative or positive in the ScrollWindowEx function, but I'm not able to make the window scroll up or down.

Answer (score 2):

```
// User clicked the top arrow.
case SB_LINEUP:

    if(si.nPos>si.nMin)
    si.nPos = si.nPos-1;
    break;

// User clicked the bottom arrow.
case SB_LINEDOWN:
    if(si.nPos<si.nMax)
    si.nPos -= 1;
    break;
```

Note that you use the same expression for both line up and line down. In both cases you decrement the position. For line down you need to increment rather than decrement.

I'd write it like this:

```
// User clicked the top arrow.
case SB_LINEUP:

    if(si.nPos>si.nMin)
        si.nPos--;
    break;

// User clicked the bottom arrow.
case SB_LINEDOWN:
    if(si.nPos<si.nMax)
        si.nPos++;
    break;
```